# Unity C# Invoke Function Freezes Program

Tags: unity

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && ammo <= 9)
        {
            ableS = false;
            while(ammo <= 9)
            {
                Invoke("bulletplus", 0.5f);
            }
            ableS = true;
        }
```

This is the main part I am having trouble with.

Down there is ALL my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 rotation = new Vector2 (0, 0);
    public float rot = 3;
    public Vector3 pos;
    public Rigidbody Orb;
    public Text ammoT;
    public int ammo = 10;
    bool ableS = true;

    void Update () {
        // Ammo
        if(ammo >= 7)
        {
            ammoT.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.green;
        } else if(ammo >= 4)
        {
            ammoT.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.yellow;
        } else {
            ammoT.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
        }
        
        // Rotation
        rotation.x += -Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");
        rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -70, 70);
        rotation.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        transform.eulerAngles = (Vector2)rotation * rot;
        pos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        
        // Shoot Choklats
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && ammo >= 1 && ableS)
        {
            ammoT.text = "Ammo: " + ammo.ToString();
            ammo -= 1;
            Rigidbody projectile = Instantiate(Orb, pos, transform.rotation);
            projectile.velocity = transform.forward * 50f;
        }

        // Reload
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && ammo <= 9)
        {
            ableS = false;
            while(ammo <= 9)
            {
                Invoke("bulletplus", 0.5f);
            }
            ableS = true;
        }
    }

    void bulletplus()
    {
        ammo += 1;
        ammoT.text = "Ammo: " + ammo.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You pointed out the exact part of the code that is making your program freeze. You have a loop with a condition (`ammo <= 9`), yet the body of the loop won't make the condition to be false. `Invoke` calls the named function at a later time, but the process that calls the named function won't run until the `Update` function has finished. Therefore, you are calling `Invoke` infinite times.

Comment: Another way to look at what Panda Pajama explained: Unity does not advance game time until Update() method is finished. So that half a second your Invoke waits for never comes.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that this line of code asks to do multiple things:

```
Invoke("bulletplus", 0.5f);
```

- **Schedule the method named "bulletplus" to be called 0.5 seconds from now.**
- Pause the execution of the current method we called it from, and let the rest of the engine continue running its updates and rendering for the frame.
- Don't resume this method until "bulletplus" has run to completion. After that, resume the calling method with its prior state on the next line after the `Invoke`.

In actual fact, it only does the first line, in bold. Pausing and resuming the calling method are not features it offers [according to the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html). You can verify this yourself with a simple test:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.LogFormat("{0}: Start starts at {1}", ++callOrder, Time.time);
    Invoke("InvokeReporter", 0.5f);
    Debug.LogFormat("{0}: Start finishes at {1}", ++callOrder, Time.time);
}

void InvokeReporter() {
    Debug.LogFormat("{0}: Invoked method runs at {1}", ++callOrder, Time.time);
}
```

[image: Output: start starts, then finishes, then the invoked method runs]

You can see `Invoke` does not add any delay between the first and second halves of `Start` - they run back-to-back in the same frame.

So, as was pointed out to you in the comments, this is an infinite loop:

```
while(ammo <= 9)
{
     Invoke("bulletplus", 0.5f);
}
```

Scheduling an invocation of "bulletplus" to happen later does not increase the value of the `ammo` variable now. So if `ammo` was less than 10 when we entered the loop, it will still be less than 10 no matter how many times we repeat the loop, and we can never escape.

Apart from a coroutine hitting a `yield` statement, Unity executes each MonoBehaviour message method completely, from top to bottom or the first `return` statement, before moving on to the next object/message or proceeding with any of the other work of the frame.

So if your `Update` method gets stuck in this infinite loop and never returns, then Unity is stuck executing it endlessly, unable to move onto the next script that needs updating, or draw a new frame, or process new input. Your game hangs because the engine can't get to updating the window.

It looks like what you want is a coroutine something like this:

```
Vector2 rotation = new Vector2 (0, 0);
public float rotationSpeed = 3;
public Rigidbody projectilePrefab;

public Text ammoText;
public int ammo = 10;
bool reloadInProgress = false;

void Update () {
    // Rotation
    rotation.x += -Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed;
    rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -70, 70);
    rotation.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rototationSpeed;
    rotation.y %= 360.0f;        
    transform.eulerAngles = rotation;

   
    // Can't shoot or start another reload while already reloading.
    if(reloadInProgress)
        return;
    

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && ammo >= 1)
    {
        UpdateAmmo(-1);
        Rigidbody projectile = Instantiate(
                                 projectilePrefab,
                                 transform.position,
                                 transform.rotation);
        projectile.velocity = transform.forward * 50f;
    }

    // Reload
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && ammo <= 9)
    {
        // Start a method that can take turns with the engine,
        // pausing for multiple frames then resuming when needed.
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
    }
}

IEnumerator Reload() {
    reloadInProgress = true;

    while(ammo <= 9) {
        // Put this coroutine on hold for a period of time, 
        // while letting the rest of the game run.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        // Then resume our execution on the next line:
        UpdateAmmo(+1);
    }

    reloadInProgress = false;
}

// Let's do this update work only when the ammo changes, not every frame.
void UpdateAmmo(int ammoChange) {
    ammo += ammoChange;
    ammoText.text = "Ammo: " + ammo.ToString();

    if(ammo >= 7) {
        ammoText.color = Color.green;
    } else if(ammo >= 4) {
        ammoText.color = Color.yellow;
    } else {
        ammoText.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is the first time I have ever asked someone and responded like this... well appreciated!!